# Function of Function notation.

Tags: functions

Suppose I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}_+ \to  [0,1]$ and another similar function $g$.
I consider $g$ to be a fixed function,  and I want to know how close $f$ is to $g$.
For this purpose, I define a `residual operator' $R$ which calculates the difference between the two functions, but *as a function of $f(x)$*.  Can I write:

$R: f \mapsto (f(x) \mapsto (f(x) - g(x)\;)$?

In other words,  the output of $Rf$ is a function whose output is the difference *evaluated* at $f(x)$.

P.s. I suppose to be more rigorous I could write this as

$R: (f,g)  \mapsto (f(x) \mapsto (f(x) - g(x)\;)$.

---

I'm getting a lot  of answers that I should write $R: (f,g) \mapsto f - g$. However,  please notice that when I plot $Rf$ I want the horizontal axis to be the value of $f(x)$.  I know this is possible in practice, because I have plotted this many times, but I'm having difficulty representing what I am calculating in function notation.

---

With the help of the very nice responses, I think I know how to write this in rigorous function notation.   The object I'm interested in is a plot, and a plot is really just a collection of points in two dimensions. How do I write "a collection of points in two dimensions"? One such collection might be written:

$\{(x(t),y(t)) \;|\; x,y: \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R} , t\ge 0\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.

My operator becomes

$R: (f,g) \mapsto \{\,(f(t),f(t)-g(t)) \;|\; f,g: \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R} , t\ge 0\}$.

In summary, we can think of $R(f,g)$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I don't see why $R(f) = f-g$ wouldn't work.

Comment: More like $R: f \mapsto ( x \mapsto  f(x) - g(x) )$, but why not simply $R(f) = f - g$?

Comment: @whpowell96   I'd like it to be a function of $f(x)$.  When I plot it, I'd like the horizontal axis to be $f(x)$.

Comment: Regarding the edit, the thing you want is not a function in general. What it sounds like you want is a parametric graph of the form $x\mapsto (f(x), f(x)-g(x))$

Comment: Yes, you have the idea.    Is $x \mapsto (f(x),f(x)-g(x))$ acctepable notation for  a function among mathematicans?   I haven't  seen this in the math papers I've  read.

Comment: Your answer is very similar to the answer  of  ioveri in a  comment.   As I understand it, he is suggesting that the operator is $R: (f-g) \mapsto f - g$, but the plot  is  a parametric  plot of $(f(x),f(x)-g(x))$.   In other words, he is using a distinct notation for the plot, as opposed to the operator.

Comment: @whpowell96 please  see my edited  question. Tanks.

Comment: It looks like the parametric plot will give you what you want, but it's worth mentioning that that won't necessarily be the plot of a function - it's possible that there are two distinct $y$ values for the same $x$ value, which can't happen for a function. But if your $f( )$ happens to be one-to-one, then you'll be okay, and the parametric plot will be identical to the plot of the function $g\circ f^{-1}$.

Comment: I agree.  My operator is giving me a set of point in the 2D plane.  Which is not the same as a function. I now see  this with the help of these comments.  Please see my edited question.